# Verification of the conceptual understanding related to eigen values

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, solution-verification, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, linear-transformations

If somebody could check whether my understanding is correct, I would be grateful.

Suppose $T$ is a linear transformation from a finite dimensional vector space $V$ to itself. Suppose I represent the transformation by matrix $A$ with respect to the ordered bases $B_1$ and $B_2$. In order to find the eigen values of this transformation, I must first find the matrix $I$ of the identity transformation with respect $B_1$ and $B_2$ only. This $I$ may not look always like the identity matrix (a diagonal matrix with 1s on diagonal and rest zero). Then I would solve the equation
$$det(A-xI) = 0.$$
Or equivalently, I first find the transformation $T-xI$ and find the matrix $A$ of this transformation and solve the equation
$$det(A)=0.$$

The reason for writing this post is that, I was mistaken that if A is matrix of linear transformation from $\mathbb{R}^n$ to $\mathbb{R}^n$ with respect to some basis pair, then eigen values of the transformation were solutions to
$$det(A-xI)=0,$$
where $I$ always represented identity matrix. What I understood now is that, this is the case only when the bases were standard bases in standard order. When the basis pair change (or the order), I must also replace $I$ with suitable matrix.

Comment: The eigenvalues of $T$ will be equal to the eigenvalues of the matrix $A$ of $T$ with respect to **a single basis** $B$. As soon as you introduce distinct bases $B_1,B_2$, you lose the eigenvalues.

Comment: I understand that if I have a single basis, then the matrix of identity transformation would be identity matrix itself. However, if I have different  base pair $B_1$ and $B_2$, I still have the notion of checking for what $x$ the linear transformation $A-xI$ is singular (where $I$ is the identity transformation) in terms of matrix of that linear transformation with respect to $B_1$ and $B_2$ . I suspect that, even then we have the notion of eigen values. Isn't it?

Comment: I understand now. It is true that if $A$ is the matrix of $T - xI$ with respect to any (possibly distinct) pair of bases, then the eigenvalues of $T$ are the values of $x$ for which $A$ fails to be invertible (i.e. $\det(A) = 0$).

Comment: Exactly. To compute the eigen values (alternatively), I may first find matrix of $T$, say $A$ with respect to given bases pair, then I compute matrix of identity transformation, say $I$ with respect to same basis pair, and then solve $$det(A-xI)=0.$$ Right?

Comment: Yes, that is a valid approach

Comment: Right. Thank you.